# Why can't I poweroff my computer if it isn't connected to a power supply?

Tags: power-management, acpi

When my computer is not plugged in the poweroff function doesn't work. It just boots up after poweroff.  Whenever I poweroff by the way of GUI clicking or typing command `poweroff` or `halt`, my computer just reboots.

- But if plugged in, my notebook works without any problem.
  Can any help me ?

Answer (score 2):

That is a hardware bug: your system does not recognize the software telling the system to stop, it then returns a non supported error/action and the operating system will just reboot.

Possible fix: set ACPI to not route IRQs.

```
 gksudo gedit /etc/default/grub
```

Find and edit the option that is:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash acpi=noirq"
```

and update grub ...

```
sudo update-grub
```

Now do a reboot and then a shutdown and see if this fixes it.